# Prove that a Sequence Approaches Infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

I have to calculate the limit of the following:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{k+1})$

I think that the answer is infinity. Explanation:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1}$ =$1$ - that I know how to prove.

However, I don't know how to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{k+1}$)=$\infty$.

If I prove that the first is lim=1, and the second is lim=$\infty$, then I can say that 1*$\infty$.=$\infty$.

Ideas are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : $\frac{k}{k+1} \ge \frac12$ then $\sum_1^n \frac{k}{k+1} \ge \frac n2$ which $\to \infty$

Intuitively, you're adding $n$ terms that get closer to 1, so you'd think that the sum gets closer to $n$ and diverges.

Comment: So I can take $\frac12$ and call it "M", and say that the sum is bigger than that M for every number? sorry for the lousy explanation.

Comment: You're summing up $n$ terms each larger than $1/2$ ...

Comment: But if k=1, than the result is excatly $\frac12$, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't change anything but I amended the hint for the sake of it

Comment: You're welcome. I'd still recommend you write the  whole proof down so you don't miss any detail

Comment: I still can't get to prove it formally. The hint does help but... how do I write it?